# Is it possible to use an HTTP PUT to submit form data?

Tags: javascript, http, http-post

Simple question: everyone knows you can POST data in a HTML form to the server, and the browser will handle serializing the data in the form.

However, is it possible to do this using a PUT verb instead? Either through Javascript or some other means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Section 9.6 on [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) states that the URI is of the resource to be put, and the web server *must not* use it towards any other resource. So, while technically you may be able to construct a server process/script that would, you should not depend on any server allowing that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could
http://www.wynia.org/wordpress/2007/03/not-just-get-and-post-http-put-and-delete-with-javascript/